# PyQt ComboBox widget not signalling when empty

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have a comboBox and the contents need to change dynamically. I also need to know when the user clicks on the comboBox. When the comboBox has content, it will fire signals, but when it's empty I don't see any signals fired at all. The following code is a toy example demonstrating that for an empty comboBox, no signal will fire.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class Ui_Example(QtGui.QDialog):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        self.dialog = Dialog
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(300,143)
        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60,20,230,20))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")

class Ui_Example_Logic(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_Example_Logic, self).__init__()

    def create_main_window(self):
        self.ui = Ui_Example()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.comboBox.highlighted.connect(self.my_highlight)
        self.ui.comboBox.activated.connect(self.my_activate)

    def my_highlight(self):
        print "Highlighted"

    def my_activate(self):
        print "Activated"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    APP = QtGui.QApplication([])
    WINDOW = Ui_Example_Logic()
    WINDOW.create_main_window()
    WINDOW.show()
    sys.exit(APP.exec_())
```

So for example, if the line below is added to the `create_main_window` function, `"activated"` and `"highlighted"` will print out on expected events, but as the code is now (with the comboBox empty) nothing will print.

```
self.ui.comboBox.addItems(['a', 'b'])
```

How can I detect if the user has interacted with the comboBox when it is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `combobox` is empty, no signal will be emitted. But you can `installEventFilter` for your combobox and reimplement `eventfilter` ([link](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/32787)). First, create filter:

```
class MouseDetector(QtCore.QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress and obj.count() == 0:
            print 'Clicked'
        return super(MouseDetector, self).eventFilter(obj, event)
```

It will be print `Clicked` when user press mouse button on empty `comboBox`, created inside `Ui_Example`. Then, install event:

```
class Ui_Example(QtGui.QDialog):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        self.dialog = Dialog
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(300,143)
        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox(Dialog)
        self.comboBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60,20,230,20))
        self.comboBox.setObjectName("comboBox")

        self.mouseFilter = MouseDetector()
        self.comboBox.installEventFilter(self.mouseFilter)
```